# Improper double integral convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to determine whether the following double integral converges

$$ \iint_D e^{-x^2-4y^2} dxdy \qquad , \qquad D = [(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq 2y] $$

So I tried the following substitution

$$ x = r \cdot \text{cos} \theta $$
$$ y = \frac{1}{2} r \cdot \text{sin} \theta$$
$$ \frac{\pi}{6} < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2} $$

But I'm getting a wrong answer $\frac{\pi}{12}$, the right answer is $\frac{\pi}{16}$, but I can't really find where i went wrong! Any tips?

Comment: Why does $\theta$ start from $\frac\pi6$?

Comment: I thought that it is the angle between the x-axis and x=2y, but I may be wrong!

Comment: To determine the range of $\theta$, you must use your exact substitution! Of course, changing the substitution will change the range of $\theta$. So, here $0\le x\leq 2y$ is equivalent to $0\le r\cos\theta\leq r\sin\theta$, then your $\theta$ belongs to $[\pi/4, \pi/2]$.

Comment: Oh that’s right! thank you for your help!:) I have a small question, when im drawing the graph, the angle is between the x axis and the line is definitely not pi/4! How come it becomes it after using polar coordinates?

Comment: Change variables $x'=x$ and $y'=2y.$ Then you will get ${1\over 2}\int\limits_{D'}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy$ $D'=\{0\le x\le y\}$ The angle is easier for determining. Moreover the answer is equal $8$ times the integral over the entire plane.